# How do I get a full recursive registry key with values using a single command in PowerShell on a remote computer?

Tags: powershell, registry

**The problem I'm trying to solve:**

I need to perform multiple search operations on this registry key, and then change a particular value once I've verified that I'm changing the right one with my script.

Workflow is as follows:

- Find correct registry key
- Verify current value of key
- Modify value of key
- Verify new value of key

This ends up being 4 operations across 16 keys for *each* server, and it's a high latency connection - it feels like it takes forever. I'd like to be able to do the search *locally* once I've grabbed the full key, which would allow me to make a single remote connection each for the first and last steps, and no connection at all for the second step - reducing my connections per server from 64 to 18 for each one.

**What sort of works:**

I can use the following command to get all of the information I actually need:

`REG QUERY \\server01\HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Vendor\App\DatabaseList /s`

This outputs all the information for the registry keys. It's human-readable, but it'd be a lot more useful as an object I can search. Obviously I could write something to parse it out, but I feel like there's got to be a better way.

An alternative solution would be to use REG EXPORT, but it looks like that only works on a local machine (e.g. using Invoke-Command) and requires a file to be written - which is possible but ugly. This would at least give me a somewhat more structured file to parse though.

**What I've tried:**

`Get-ChildItem HKLM:\$registryKey` seems to give me everything *except* for the values. If they're there, I can't find out how to pull them out of the object. All the examples I've found seem to use `Get-ItemProperty` to grab the actual values in a separate command.

`Get-ItemProperty` looks like it can get me the values, but I need to have the specific key I'm querying (which I don't have until I search for it, of course.)

There appears to be a number of solutions out there - the problem is that all of the solutions seem to assume that network access is zero-cost, which isn't the case here.

**What I really want:**

A single command which makes a **single** network request which returns a structured object with all the information contained in the REG QUERY command above. I can figure out the rest.

Note that I'm trying to minimize the number of network requests as much as possible here. I already have a solution which executes the workflow listed in the first part, using REG QUERY. The code to parse out those requests is a total hack, and I'd like something more Powershell-native. However, the hack *works*, so there's no value (in this case) in re-implementing it differently if I can't also get a performance improvement out of it.

Other note: I'm limited to Powershell 5 if everything can run locally, Powershell 2 (don't ask, lol) if I'm invoking the command on a remote machine. I'll take a Powershell 7 solution if it's all doable against machines running Powershell 2.

Comment: Use PowerShell remoting (`Invoke-Command -Computer $servers { ... }`), perform all remote operations together inside the script block (`{ ... }`) and return only the result to the caller, as output from the script block.

Comment: "`Get-ItemProperty` looks like it can get me the values, but I need to have the specific key I'm querying" - they work together: `Get-ChildItem ... |Get-ItemProperty -Name propertyName` :)

Comment: @mklement0 - Clever, I see what you're getting at there. I'll have to see if I can structure it so it'll do all the stuff I need it to do inside... I guess it'd basically be a full script invoked on the remote computer, huh? Not sure if it's practical in this case, but definitely clever.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - bloody pipelines, never use 'em. ;)


(no, really, it tends to make scripts very confusing for me to parse, i am not a good powershell scripter...)


I was trying to do the operations separately - ```$foo = Get-Childitem $regkey;Get-ItemProperty $foo``` and the latter command was giving me errors about wanting a path.


Combined with @mklement0's answer above, this might fulfill the requirement I have - doing invoke-command with what you suggested without the -name flag dumps everything, operates on the remote server, and seems to give me the object I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Send a script to run on the remote machine instead of running it from the local machine.

```
$credential = Get-Credential
$registryKey = "HKLM:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\themes"
$computers = 'web02','dhcp01','mail01'

$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
    
    $keys = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $using:registryKey

    foreach($key in $keys) {
        $obj = [pscustomobject]@{ 
            Name = $key.Name
            Properties = @{}
        }

        foreach($property in $key.Property) {
            $obj.Properties[$property] = $key.GetValue($property)
        }

        Write-Output $obj
    }
}


foreach($entry in $result) {
    Write-Verbose -Verbose ("{0} -- {1}" -f $entry.PSComputerName, $entry.Name)
    foreach($key in $entry.Properties.Keys) {
        Write-Verbose -Verbose ("- $key == {0}" -f $entry.Properties[$key])
    }
}
```